# How to prevent Shinyapp.io to change URL every time we republish

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

I typically publish my app the standard way:

[image]

The first time I publish, I get this URL:

```
 https://peveralldubois.shinyapps.io/myapp/
```

But the second and third time I republish I get this:

```
https://peveralldubois.shinyapps.io/myapp2/
https://peveralldubois.shinyapps.io/myapp3/
```

This happen, even after I delete the app in Shinyapp.io dashboard or `Create New Title`in RStudio.

How can I prevent it so that it permanently use?

```
https://peveralldubois.shinyapps.io/myapp/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are publishing a R markdown document, I believe you want to update to the latest version of Rstudio which will give you the ability to publish to RPubs (https://rpubs.com/).

When you are publishing an updated Shiny app to shinyapps.io, the Publish UI should show an "update" option instead of the input box to put in a new title.

Comment: I'm using RMarkdown with Runtime:Shiny. I tried your suggestion with "Update" option. It still can't bring me to original `https://peveralldubois.shinyapps.io/myapp/` even after I delete all the app in Shinyapp.io dashboard

Comment: I was able to reproduce your behavior one time then it worked for me every time after - I am wondering if this is a Rstudio bug.  Does anything change if you exit and reopen Rstudio, click down arrow next to publish icon, select myapp, and then publish?

Comment: Also, try publishing using the console with verbose logging.  For example:
    `library(rsconnect)`
    `deployApp(appFiles="test.Rmd", appName="myapp", logLevel="verbose")`
and sharing the log here.

Comment: @neversaint did you ever figure this out? I had never run into this issue before but now am.